# CLion: Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible with requested version ""

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, clion

I am trying to use Qt 6.0.2 with CLion. I get a strange error that states: "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible
with requested version ""." It seems like the requested version is not filled in but I do not know where to fill in the requested version.+

This is my code for my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(jerseytraffic)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 6)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt6::Core)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
if (WIN32)
    set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt${QT_VERSION}${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()
```

Here is a picture of the MinGW configuration in Toolchains

[image]

Comment: Does the version of cmake you're using support qt 6? It seems even the latest version doesn't support qt 6 natively https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Qt 6 documenation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html#build-a-c-gui-executable):

> For find_package to be successful, CMake must find the Qt installation. There are different ways you can tell CMake about Qt:
>
> - Set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH environment variable to include the Qt 6 installation prefix.
> - Set the CMake cache variable CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to include the Qt 6 installation prefix.

For example, following code is needed:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "D:/SDK/Qt/6.0.1/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/")
```